# $\sqrt{5} \in \mathbb{R}$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

I have to show that $\sqrt{5} \in \mathbb{R}$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$ and then I have to find $Irr(\sqrt{5}, \mathbb{Q})$.

How can I show that $\sqrt{5} \in \mathbb{R}$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$ ??

Comment: Let's begin by recalling the definition of *algebraic over $\Bbb{Q}$*. What was it again? It takes a while getting used to the way definitions work, but they form the ultimate test. We often build bits of theory to help us check that entity A deserves to be called B, but the definition is the "go to" tool.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen $a$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$ if there is a non-zero $f(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ with  $f(a)=0$, right?

So, do we have to find such a $f$, and the show that it is the $Irr(a, \mathbb{Q})$??

Comment: Correct. This is not very hard. What is the defining property of $\sqrt5$? Can you take advantage of that?

Comment: $$a=\sqrt{5} \Rightarrow a^2=5 \Rightarrow a^2-5=0$$ So $a=\sqrt{5}$ is the root of $f(x)=x^2-5$.

Comment: Well done, Mary. Now proving that $f(x)$ is the minimal polynomial will require some tools/results. Have you covered the fact that the minimal polynomial is always irreducible?

Comment: I think that every number you can represent with a finite number of $+,-,\times,\div$ and $\sqrt{}$ over algebraic numbers is algebraic (and $5$ is such number).

Answer (score 3):

$\sqrt 5$ is a solution of $X^2-5\in\mathbb Q[X]$, moreover, by Eisenstein criterion, this polynomial is irreducible !

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Try find a nontrivial polynomial $f(x)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$  such that $f(\sqrt{5})=0.$

Comment: of cource. corrected